# Xamarin forms custom scrollview showing weird behavior

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a customized ScrollView as per the requirement which is based on the [TLScrollView](https://github.com/fabiocozzolino/TitiusLabs.Xamarin/blob/master/TitiusLabs.Forms/Controls/TLScrollView.cs).

Now when I am adding some data to it there is weird behaviour that I noticed recently a part of the screen area is unclickable, And the rest of the part works fine.

Now the same code works like a charm on Android but iOS is showing this weird behaviour,

Xaml:

```
  <controls:TLScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White"
          x:Name="ListAddons" ItemsSource="{Binding ListAddons}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags = "All"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds = "0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0">

                <controls:TLScrollView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin = "0, 5, 0, 0">
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" InputTransparent="true"  RowSpacing = "0" ColumnSpacing = "0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="45.0*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="45*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}"
                   ErrorPlaceholder = "nopreviewlandscape" LoadingPlaceholder = "loadingicon"
                              Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                              VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                    <Label x:Name="lblRecommendationsName"  Margin="0" Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                  LineBreakMode="WordWrap" XAlign="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource gray_text_color}"
                                  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2"
                                  Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource RecommendationName}">
                                        <Label.FontFamily>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="OpenSans-Light" />
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="OpenSans-Light" />
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.FontFamily>
                                        <Label.TextColor>
                                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                                <On Platform="Android" Value="#000000"></On>
                                            </OnPlatform>
                                        </Label.TextColor>
                                    </Label>

                                    <BoxView WidthRequest="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource separator_color}"
                                      Grid.RowSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource BoxViewHomeStyle}">
                                    </BoxView>

                                </Grid>
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AddonsClickCommand,Source={x:Reference ListAddons}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding CategoryId}"
                                  />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:TLScrollView.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:TLScrollView>
```

First, I thought there must be some sort of an overlapping in there which might be causing this but then I realized that the same code was working on Android devices and causing this on iOS.

The part of the image that is unclickable is inside the black box everywhere else the click event works well. [image: Unclickable image]

Comment: Which ios deivce  did you run ?

Comment: iPhone X,6,7,8,6s(Physical devices) and none of them seem to get the touch at that position

Comment: The area of  unclickable is in toolbar?

Comment: No its not this is not the toolbar this is part of the screen around in the middle, i have only added the part of the screen that was relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure what was causing the issue but updating to the latest version of Xamarin.Forms fixed the bug!

I updated to Xamarin.Forms version 4.5.0.396

Feel free to get back if you are facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may have nothing to do with this problem but I think "Grid.RowSpan" of BoxView may cause problem.

The Grid have only three rows(0-2 rows) definitions but BoxView specified to merge 1 to 4 rows.

```
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="45.0*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="45*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

```
<BoxView WidthRequest="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource separator_color}"
                                      Grid.RowSpan="4" Style="{StaticResource BoxViewHomeStyle}">
                                    </BoxView>
```